# z-index is not working for navigation bar

Tags: css, z-index, navbar

I have a drop-down CSS menu. The drop down `<div>` should start above the page, behind my fixed navigation bar and when a navigation button is "moused over". It uses a CSS transition to move the submenu down the page, making it visible.

The problem is.. it keeps rendering the submenu above my navigation bar (in terms of z-index). I need it to render behind the navigation bar.

[Click here to see the webpage](http://www.obsojb.com)
(The page is intentionally aligned to the left for now - ignore this)

Here is how the HTML is layed out:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Title 1</a></li> <!-- has no submenu -->
    <li><a href="/">Title 2</a>
      <div>
        <!-- Submenu Content -->
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
#nav {
    position:absolute;
    width:<?php echo ($navbutwidth*$numititles)+($numititles-1); ?>px;
    background-color:<?php echo $colnavbg; ?>;
    z-index:5 !important;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:<?php echo $navbarwidth; ?>px;
    z-index:3 !important;
}
#nav ul li {
    float:left;
}   
#nav ul li > a {
    width:<?php echo ($navbutwidth-16); ?>px;
    height:<?php echo $navbutheight; ?>px;
    line-height:<?php echo $navbutheight; ?>px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-left:1px Solid <?php echo $colnavbutborder; ?>;
    padding-left:15px;
    background-color:<?php echo $colnavbutbg; ?>;
    color:<?php echo $colnavbuttxt; ?>;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
}   
#nav ul li > a:hover {
    background-color:<?php echo $colnavbutbghov; ?>;
    color:<?php echo $colnavbuttxthov; ?>;
}   
#nav ul li > div {
    position:absolute;
    top:-<?php echo $navsubbutheight-$navbutheight; ?>px;
    left:0px;
    width:<?php echo $navsubbutwidth; ?>px;
    height:<?php echo $navsubbutheight-1; ?>px;
    text-align:left;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    background-color:<?php echo $colsubnavbutbg; ?>;
    border-top:1px Solid #FFF;
    border-bottom:1px Solid #FFF;
    z-index:1 !important;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}   
#nav ul li:hover > div {
    top:<?php echo $navbutheight; ?>px;
    display:block;
}
#nav ul li > div:hover {
    background-color:<?php echo $colnavbutbghov; ?>;        
}
```

Comment: <div><!-- Submenu Content --></div> direct decendant of <ul>  is not valid

Comment: Sorry.. that div should be wrapped in the <li> tag. I'll edit the OP

Comment: Why? If you follow the link, that bit works perfectly fine. It drops the menu down when you hover over the `<li>` and it changes the background colour when you hover over the `<div>`

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: relative; z-index: 1000;` to `.a1`.

Having `overflow: hidden` on your ul will prevent anything outside that ul from showing up.

Comment: Okay this kinda worked. Parts of it are still showing because of the rounded corners.. which is slightly annoying. What is it about relative positioning that makes z-index work?

Comment: .. plus it still loads behind the content section

Comment: Scratch that.. It's not loading behind the page. It's not rendering there at all. Once it goes below the lowest point in the FIXED header it just disappears

Comment: For z-index to work, two conditions have to be true. Each element has to have position, whether it be relative or absolute doesn't matter. Secondly, the two elements have to be at the same level, or siblings.

Comment: You have `overflow: hidden` on your ul.

Comment: Okay that's a huge improvement.
Now.. my only problem is the it still shows above the header (rather than the navbar). www.obsojb.com
is this fixable?

Comment: You can add, `visibility: hidden` on the normal state, and `visibility: visible` on the hover state

Comment: Good workaround, although you can still see the `<div>` during the animation. Is there a way to get it to move behind the header div? Or is z-index not capable of this?

Comment: It's inside the header div, so it can't be behind it. You would need to have an element that this submenu is not inside of. You can see this by using the `.a1` class. If you add `width: 800%; background: #333;` to it, you'll see it blocks the submenu from being visible - because it has a higher z-index and is not a parent element. This is the problem with having the submenu slide in from behind the header.